# sign in routing process

Tags: html, express

I had web portal like event booking in that the user no login is necessary at first when the user choose the ticket and to payment we need that user to sign in. in that i have routed that to my sign in page after sign in it goes to first page of web portal where I have linked but user need to continue payment after sign in user after sign in no need to select the ticket for that what I need to do.

I need to make the process continue after selecting ticket and the if the user doesn't sign in need to sign in and then make payment

If the user get sign in at starting he want continue to events displaying page(I had done this) when I do above process it continue from first page

```
//app.js
app.get('/signin', function (req, res) {
  res.render('signin', { });
});


//login.js
app.post("/signin", function (req, res) {
  sess = req.session;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  const userData = {
    email: email.trim(),
    password: password.trim()
  };

  User.findOne({ email: userData.email }, (err, user) => {
    console.log ("user...", user);
    if (err) { throw err; }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({
        status: 'Error',
        msg: 'User details is not found for this email, please register....'
      });
    }

    user.comparePassword(userData.password, (passwordErr, isMatch) => {
      if (err) { throw err; }
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.json({
          status: 'Error',
          msg: 'Incorrect email or password, please try again..'
        });
      } else {
        sess.user = user;
        res.redirect("/eventica");
      } 
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user selects the ticket you can add the ticket ID into the session

```
  app.post("/ticket/:id", function (req, res) {
     sess = req.session;
     sess.selected_ticket = req.params.id; //store the selected ticket in session

     if(!userLoggedIn()){
        return res.redirect('/signin'); //This will take you to sign in page
     }

     return res.redirect('/makepayment');//This will take you to payment page
  }


  app.get("/makepayment", function (req, res) {
      sess = req.session;
      let price = Ticket.find({sess.ticket_id}).price(); //Do price search here from database

      if(!userLoggedIn()){
         return res.redirect('/signin'); //This will take you to sign in page
      }
      res.render('paymentPage', { price:price });

   }
```

> I just assumed some of the routes and variables here bt I hope you get the idea of how to do it. Simply store the ticket_id of selected ticket in session even if user is not logged in and after logging in you can just use the ticket_id stored in session for other processes.
>
> **Remember session is not only for storing user information.**